# Looping through a list of tables in python

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a list of tables containing some data and a fitter script that runs on a data set. The fitter generates a fit and then outputs some fit parameters. I want to automate the process -- to run a for loop that loops through a portion of the elements in the table and outputs their fit parameters.
I can run the fitter on every one of the elements with this code:

`import tables`

`from function.fitter import Fitter`

`hdf2 = tables.openFile('data.waveforms.hdf5')`

`for element in data.waveforms:`

`fitter = Fitter(element)`

The elements are titled in this way: data0101, data0102, (for set one) ... , data0201, data0202 (set number 2), etc.

How can I loop through only the ten elements of set number 1: data0101, data0102, ... data0110, for example?

Answer (score 1):

Either slice it (`for ... in data.waveforms[:10]`) or use [`itertools.islice()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice).

Comment: Great, thanks. I modified the code using islice():

`for element in islice(data.waveforms, 1, 60):`

So I can choose which elements to run the fitter on by their number (their order in the table), but it looks like islice() wants integers for the start and stop conditions. Can I tell islice() to start at data0101 and stop at data0160 instead of starting at element 1 and going until element 60?

Comment: Unfortunately no. You'll have to look at the other `itertools` functions or perhaps even a custom generator for that.

Comment: `itertools.takewhile` would be ideal for checking the names of the elements (provided they're in order like that).

Comment: To use takewhile(), I need a predicate to test. So I need to read the last four characters of the element name and compare them to my start and stop conditions?